# How do I add a signed certificate to an existing Google Cloud vm

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I have a GCE instance running that I would like to add a Google Cloud managed certificate which was created via the `gcloud`command.

Everything I'm reading wants me to either have instance groups or backend proxies.

None of this seems to be relevant for a single VM that I want to attach a certificate to and I don't wish to destroy the VM or put it in an instance group.

Comment: What are you running on that GCE instance? Nginx? Why do you need to add the certificate?

Comment: Mail and https, currently the machine has a self signed cert.

Comment: Could you please add more details since "mail and https" is really broad, also this isn't related with programming you might want to move the question over Serverfault.

Comment: You cannot use a Google Managed SSL certificate on your VM instances. Google does not provide you with the certificate private key. You can upload your own SSL certificate (Google Self Managed SSL Certificates). Can you show the `gcloud` command that you used to create a managed SSL certificate? I am not aware of a gcloud command to do this.